# issue with reciving data from WebApi in AngularJs Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-service, angular-promise

I'm gonna use AngularJS Service in my applications and make everything clean and nice.. I followed some articles for this purpose. but its seems not completed. Right ??
I don't see any error or something but when i set Alert(data); i'll get undefined error. what's my missed work to do here ?

My App.js

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
```

My Service.js

```
var serverPath = 'http://url/api/locations';

app.service('testService', function($http) {
  this.getLocations = function() {
    $http.get(serverPath).success(function(data) {
      return data;
    });
  };
});
```

My controller.js

```
app.controller('LocationsController', function ($scope, testService) {
  $scope.locations = testService.getLocations();
});
```

and my UI

```
<div ng-controller="LocationsController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="location in locations">
      {{ location.locationName }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you run `Alert(data)`?

Comment: @gtlambert inside my LocationsController. I deleted this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get data from asynchronous call directly as soon as you do request for the data. You should follow the promise pattern to deal with asynchronous data.

I'd like to point out several mistakes which you did.

1. You should have return `$http.get` promise from the service method `getLocations`, so that you can place `.then` function over that method.
2. Then inside controller call service method `getLocations` from controller and place `.then` function, out of which 1st will get call when ajax succeed and 2nd will get called on ajax error.
   function of `.then`

   ```
   this.getLocations = function () {
       return $http.get(serverPath); //return promise object
   };
   ```

**Controller**

```
testService.getLocations().then(function(response){ //success function
     $scope.locations = response.data;
}, function(error){ //error function
     console.log("Some error occurred", error)
});
```

Comment: @MortezaAghili glad to hear that.. Thanks :)

Comment: can i use this method for post or put methods?

Comment: @MortezaAghili what do you mean by `this`?

Comment: Let me check and if was an error i will explain it for you. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do this since $http has promise inside

I like to add an initialization step to page.

inside Service:

```
$http.get(serverPath)
  .success(function(data) {
    return data;
  })
  .error(function(err) {
    console.log("some error occured");
    return err;
  });
```

controller:

```
app.controller('LocationsController', function($scope, testService) {
  $scope.init = function() {
    testService.getLocations()
      .success(function(res) {
        $scope.locations = res;
      })
      .error(function(err) {
        console.log("LocationsController, getLocations error:", err);
        // alert(err);
      });
  };
});
```

Markup:

```
<div ng-controller="LocationsController" ng-init="init()">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="location in locations">
      {{ location.locationName }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can also add ng-hide if you the http call take some time.

Comment: This will only work if the service actually returns the promise, which it isn't currently doing.

Comment: No, .success() and .error() both return the original promise for additional chaining.  (And you shouldn't use those anymore - they're deprecated.)

Comment: @Dave I think you are talking about, what I did in ^ above answer :p

Comment: I see. ```$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);``` I will just leave it there.